# google colab wont finish downloading file

Tags: jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

I am working on my notebook in google colab.
To save my progress I imported the files module from `from google.colab import files` and I am using `files.download(file_name)` function to download the file with my data.

However, When I run the code it seems like the command is stuck. The output I get is the following
[image: progress bar for downloading image]

This loading bar is running for couple hours and wont finish (it didn't make any progress visually speaking).

The file isn't more than a few dozens MB and I was able to download it with the colab's file explorer

[image]

Using this method it took me no more than a few minutes to download the file

Comment: Facing the same issue, except I am using a corporate version of colab where I cannot see the sidebar to download the model. Any help here is appreciated!

Comment: Run into the same problem. Did you find any solutin?

Comment: Sadly, no. If you do find the solution I’d like to know

Comment: Nope, in the end I did it manually